# Unitt websocket library cannot ope the socket on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services

I researched how to integrate Web Socket functionality into iOS apps and encountered some problems. Did everything as in tutorial( http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient ), but get some strange errors:

`Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused"`

What the problem could be caused by? Here is my project https://github.com/artem888/WebSocketTest

I also tried to use Socket Rocket( https://github.com/square/SocketRocket ), but with this I dont receive delegate messages at all. Here is the project source https://github.com/artem888/WebSocketTest2

Would be appreciate for the answers, cause my introductional trip to WebSocket on iOS was pretty embarassing :D

Artem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Socket Rocket the problem was that `SRWebSocket` MUST be an iVar otherwise it will not receive any delegate messages.

```
@implementation TCViewController {
    SRWebSocket *_webSocket;
}
```

and init like this:

```
    _webSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ws://localhost:9000/chat"]]];
    _webSocket.delegate = self;

    [_webSocket open];
```

Still appreciate answer about Unitt.

Comment: Can you point me to some sample code for using the Unitt library. I am happy to help, but I can't find any code where you are using it.